# storing pictures for my website, can i use flickr or photobucket as host

Tags: image, facebook, twitter, store

I need to store pictures on my websites posted by users.

Facebook has their own internal way/system.

Twitter however uses photobucket to host the pictures

Could I use filckr or photobucket to host photos for my website? Or for them its more like a partnership...

what are the alternatives if I don't want to store all those images on my server, for the reason that I just don't have the $ for space =(

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox could be an option. You get couple of gigabytes for free. You can make a directory with pictures public and put the URLs to the pictures on your website.

Comment: I am sure I will go over the gigabytes and I will not have the $ to pay =( what if i just tell people to upload to imgur? seems easy right?